# Error message Query Cancelled on User's Request

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I'm getting this error every once in a while.
I'm passing through to AWS Redshift using SAS ETL tool.
When running the statement failed, locally, on Aginity or SQL-Workbench, 
it completes successfully.
When I log into these clients using the SAS ETL user - still completes successfully.
I have 2 DBs using the same ODBC and only one DB returns this error, so it is definitely not a driver thing.
It could fail for just about every job SAS sends, so it's not a problem with SAS.

Set_timeout is set to maximum.

Could someone please suggest what might be the problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the statement_timeout to 0 might not be sufficient, as stated in the documentation:

> If WLM timeout (max_execution_time) is also specified as part of a WLM configuration, the lower of statement_timeout and max_execution_time is used.

from http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_statement_timeout.html